# IPP requesting-user-name in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, printing

When I use ipads to print to a uniFlow server, the ipp requesting-user-name attribute is set to guest. Does anyone know if this can be modified in the ipad using profiles or any other option to make it possible to identify the user from her ipad?

The printserver and ipads are located on different subnets and DNS-SD is configured to make the printers visible in ios, because of this mDNS and reverse-lookup is not an option to get the hostname (identity).

Kind Regards
//Per